# Why do Unity UI toggle groups update *after* the default time in Execution Order settings?

Tags: unity, game-loop, unity-ui

Why is toggle group after default time in the default script execution order in Unity?

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Comment: Is it because you would want it to toggle slightly after pressing?

Comment: Not just pressing. Imagine another script, executing in the default time block, toggles one of the toggle group members. What would happen if the toggle group had already finished its update for that frame, and didn't get a second chance at-bat? 